# Validation error: ul not allowed as child of element span

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I do not understand why the WC3 validator is flagging this HTML as invalid, the error it reports back is...

> Element ul not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

I'm using HTML5, and this code is for breadcrumbs.

```
<span class="bread">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span>` by definition is an inline element (so you use it inside a paragraph, for example), while `<ul>` is a block element (which is its own little chunk of space, usually with space before/after it unlike `<span>`).

Other people have had the same issue, and end up using `<div>` tags instead. See [Is it possible to put a list inside a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727921/is-it-possible-to-put-a-list-inside-a-span-tag)

Answer (score 3):

According to the html5 recommendations the [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) element can only contain [phrasing-content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1). The [`<ul>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) element is not in the list of phrasing content tags. The html validation engine is enforcing those rules.

You can use a [`<div>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) as the container instead.

Answer (score 2):

if you style the div as 'display:inline' it should nominally conform to the rule, whilst behaving exactly like a span :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it as a breadcrumb, it's a navigational element, so `<nav>` makes the most sense as the container of your `<ul>`. Otherwise, give the UL a class of "breadcrumb" `<ul class="breadcrumb">` and style it based on its class.

Answer (score 0):

USE `<div>`

```
<div class="bread">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

instead of `<span>`

```
<span class="bread">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```